# tell perl compiler to cache values inside loop

Tags: perl, optimization, loops, keyword

is there a way to tell/force the perl compiler to cache values inside a loop?

of course I can create my values outside of the loop, but with increasing complexity of code, I find it more readable to create the values inside of the loop, although they don't change

for example:

```
my $key = shift;
my @input = @_;
my %output;
foreach(@input) {
    my $output_tmp = specialOperation($_);
    ...
    my $key_tmp = constantOperation($key);
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    ...
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

`$keyTmp` has the same value in every iteration and I would like the compiler to cache it

in a regex you can use the `o-flag`
is there something similar, e.g. a keyword, to accomplish this?

Comment: Just put the call `my $key_tmp = constantOperation($key);` before the foreach loop.

Comment: as mentioned that's a possibility I try to avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really any additional complexity introduced by altering your code as follows:

```
my $key_tmp = constantOperation($key);
my %output
foreach ( @input ) {
    my $output_tmp = special_operation($_);
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

But accepting for a moment that you have a reasonable undisclosed argument for why you wouldn't want to just do that, another possibility (if constantOperation is a pure function) is to use Memoize.

```
use Memoize;
memoize 'constantOperation';

my $key = shift;
my @input = @_;
my %output;
foreach( @input ) {
    my $output_tmp = special_operation;
    my $key_tmp = constantOperation($key);
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

The latter doesn't avoid the repeated function call, but does cause caching within the function called constantOperation, so subsequent calls with a previously used parameter will provide a cached result.

Going back to the first example, you could just move the "my" declaration out of the loop, and then within the loop use something like this:  `$key_tmp //= constantOperation($key);`.  Here's how that might look:

```
my $key = shift;
my @input = @_;
my %output;
my $key_tmp;
foreach( @input ) {
    my $output_tmp = special_operation;
    $key_tmp //= constantOperation($key);
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

And this being Perl, there's always one more way to do it.  Enable the 'state' feature, and change `my $key_tmp` to `state $key_tmp`.  Here's how that might look:

```
use feature 'state';
my $key = shift;
my @input = @_;
my %output;
foreach( @input ) {
    my $output_tmp = special_operation;
    state $key_tmp = constantOperation($key);
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: yes ``state`` is exactly what I was searching for. I didn't know, it's possible to use it in loops too.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$key_tmp` outside the loop, then within the loop check to see if it has already been assigned before recalculating it:

```
my ($key, @input) = @_;
my %output;
my $key_tmp;

foreach(@input) {
    my $output_tmp = specialOperation($_);
    ...
    $key_tmp = constantOperation($key) unless $key_tmp;
    my $specialKey = specialOperation2($_,$key_tmp);
    ...
    $output{$specialKey} = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: that's the same way DavidO wrote with ``//=``

Comment: @Hachi Not quite the same; `$key_tmp = constantOpearation($key) unless $key_tmp;` would fail if a possible legitimate value returned by `constantOperation` evaluates to Boolean 'false'.  `unless defined $key_tmp;` would probably be more robust (and is closer in function to what I suggested).  His solution here is more like `$key_tmp ||= ....` instead of `$key_tmp //= ....`.  I chose the latter because I considered it less fragile.

Comment: and what you did is translated to ``unless defined $key_tmp``, I know. I just wanted to say it's the same approach, not that it does the same